# hive, ask for files within specific range

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Suppose on HDFS I have file with following content: `data1-2018-01-01.txt`, `data1-2018-01-02.txt`, `data1-2018-01-03.txt`, `data1-2018-01-04.txt`, `data1-2018-01-06.txt`

Now I want to query files based on date:

```
select * from mytable where date > 2018-01-03 and date < 2018-01-06 ;
```

And my question: is it possible to create an external table just on these files satisfying my query? Or maybe you have any workaround?

I know, I could use partitions but they require to fetch the data manually when the new data set arrives.

Comment: Suppose on HDFS I have file with following content: data1-2018-01-01.txt - Directory you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those file into a directory and create new table on top of it.
Also Hive has INPUT__FILE__NAME virtual column, you can use it for filtering:

```
where INPUT__FILE__NAME like '%2018-01-03%'
```

Also it is possible to use substr or regexp_extract to get date from filename , then use `IN` or `>, <` to filter them.